# Cocos2d Time based Animation and Frame based Animation confusion ?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Cocos2d-android - I have an animation which has 5 Frames they are close cropped images. Now I want Sprite to do animation as well as Move in X direction.i.e. I have a player running which gets collided with obstacle and falls down.

```
gameOverAnimation =CCSprite.sprite("gmovr")
gameOverAnimation.setAnchorPoint(0, 0);
gameOverAnimation.setPosition(340.0f, 200.0f);
addChild(gameOverAnimation,10);
CCIntervalAction action1 = CCAnimate.action(mEndAnimation, false); 
action1.setDuration(1.0f);
CCIntervalAction delay = CCDelayTime.action(0.68f);
CCMoveBy actionBy = CCMoveBy.action(1.0f, CGPoint.ccp(-340,0)); 
CCIntervalAction seq1 = CCSpawn.actions(action1,actionBy);
//CCSpawn spawn = CCSpawn.actions(action1, actionBy);
                CCSequence sequence1 = CCSequence.actions(seq1,CCCallFuncN.action(this,"gameOver"));
                gameOverAnimation.runAction(sequence1);
```

And please can some explain me proper difference between **Frame based and Time based animation**. I want to do time based animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean under Frame based animation? Almost all the actions in cocos2d engine divided into 2 groups. Instant and interval actions. Instant actions are continuous actions. CCAnimate action that use frames is subclass of CCActionInterval, so it is "time based" action

Comment: Morion i am very new to Cocos2d.I am an application programmer but just now thought abt shifting to game, so in a learning phase.. while reading about animation i found there are two animation type. So i wanted to know about cocos2d how animation works. Thanks for your detailed explanation but I am still confused abt difference between CCInterval and CCMoveto ? What is the difference between two i mean if i do CCInterval a = CCMoveto.actions ? will it be same as CCMoveto a = CCMoveto.actions ??

Comment: CCMoveTo is just a subclass of CCActionInterval. After creation you don't need to know, what action do you use. If you will call `runAction` method, it will be not any difference, how action declared(I mean CCMoveTo, CCRotateBy, or something else). For compiler it will be enough to know that the parameter is just some subclass of CCAction class, because during running actions has the same interface.

Comment: Thank you so much Morion...Thank you for clearing my concepts